# Embedding of fractional Sobolev space into BMO

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that $$\Vert u \Vert_{BMO(\mathbb R^2)} \lesssim_{s} \Vert u \Vert_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^2)},$$
for $s \in (0,1)$, where $\dot H^s(\mathbb R)$ is the homogeneous fractional Sobolev space?

Answer (score 2):

For every $s\in(0,1)$, $H^s(\mathbb{R}^2)$ fails to embed into $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$, for some $p:=p(s)$ large enough. Hence your inequality can not be true, as BMO functions are locally $L^p$ (with a continuous embedding on bounded domains) for every $p<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the critical $p(s)$ for the embedding?

Comment: You are welcome, It is $p(s)=2/(1-s)$.

Comment: Isn't this strange, since the embedding into $BMO$ works with $\dot H^1$?

Comment: There is nothing strange, it's the classical Sobolev embedding.